# Why does accessing my capture-by-reference variable cause a segfault in my lambda function?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I am going to give a presentation on lambda expressions for our local C/C++ Meetup, so I am preparing several examples to demonstrate how lambda expressions can solve certain tasks.

One of the examples is to create a `qsort` function that takes a lambda expression for the comparison function.  It works fine for the simple case of `sort_ascending()` below, but for `sort_descending()`, where I include a counter integer that is captured by reference and incremented with each call to the lambda expression, I get a segfault at the first attempt to increment the counter.

I've looked at the lambda expression documentation I could find, especially [cppreference.cpp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).  As far as I can tell, there's no reason why `testcount` in `sort_descending` should be out-of-scope: `testcount` is in the same stack frame as the call to `qsort_l`, and the lambda expression that captured `testcount` is no longer used when `qsort_l` returns.

```
// -*- compile-command: "g++ -std=c++11 -ggdb -Wno-pmf-conversions -Wall -Werror -Weffc++ -pedantic -o minfail minfail.cpp" -*-

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_ints(const int* arr, int count)
{
   for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
   {
      if (i)
         putchar(' ');

      printf("%3d", arr[i]);
   }

   putchar('\n');
}

class Compar_Base
{
public:
   virtual ~Compar_Base()              { }
   virtual int comp(const void* left, const void* right) const = 0;

   static int compare(const void* left, const void* right, void* obj)
   {
      return static_cast<Compar_Base*>(obj)->comp(left,right);
   }
};

template <typename Func>
class Compar_Concrete : public Compar_Base
{
   Func &m_f;
public:
   Compar_Concrete(Func f) : m_f(f) { }
   virtual ~Compar_Concrete()       { }
   Compar_Concrete(const Compar_Concrete&) = delete;
   Compar_Concrete& operator=(const Compar_Concrete&) = delete;
   virtual int comp(const void* left, const void* right) const
   {
      return m_f(left,right);
   }
};

/** Shiny, new qsort for lambda expressions. */
template <typename Func>
void qsort_l(void *base, size_t member_count, size_t member_size, Func f)
{
   Compar_Concrete<Func> comp(f);
   qsort_r(base, member_count, member_size, Compar_Base::compare, &comp);
}

void sort_ascending(int* intlist, int count)
{
   auto f = [](const void* left, const void* right) -> int
   {
      return *static_cast<const int*>(left) - *static_cast<const int*>(right);
   };

   qsort_l(intlist, count, sizeof(int), f);
}

void sort_descending(int* intlist, int count)
{
   int testcount = 0;
   auto f = [&testcount](const void* left, const void* right) -> int
   {
      // Segmentation fault at this line:
      ++testcount;

      return *static_cast<const int*>(right) - *static_cast<const int*>(left);
   };

   qsort_l(intlist, count, sizeof(int), f);

   printf("\nIt took %d tests to complete the sort.\n", testcount);
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int ilist[] = {1,9,2,8,3,7,4,6,5};
   int count = sizeof(ilist) / sizeof(int);

   print_ints(ilist,count);
   sort_ascending(ilist, count);
   print_ints(ilist,count);
   sort_descending(ilist, count);
   print_ints(ilist,count);
}
```

I compiled the code above using g++ versions 4.8.4 and 5.4.0 with the same result (ie a segfault). You can see the compiler options in use by looking at the `compile-command` variable declared at the top of the code listing.

Comment: Where exactly that segfault occurred? Did you already inspect your code with the debugger?

Comment: Ugly code. Use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) + [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: Make it `qsort_r(..., static_cast<Compar_Base*>(&comp));` You are passing a wrong pointer to `Compar_Base::compare`

Comment: `Compar_Concrete(Func f) : m_f(f) { }` This ends up with a dangling reference - you bind a reference to the parameter passed by value, which is destroyed when constructor returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Func &m_f;
```

This is a class member, which is a reference. Here's your constructor:

```
Compar_Concrete(Func f) : m_f(f) { }
```

The `m_f` member is initialized to a reference to the constructor's `f` parameter.

Unfortunately, this parameter gets passed by value. When the constructor ends and terminates, `f` goes out of scope and gets destroyed, leaving a dangling reference in the class member.

Subsequent usage of `m_f` ends up dereferencing an invalid reference, and results in undefined behavior. That's at least one obvious bug.

The entire code is full of type-unsafe generic `void *` which are probably hiding a few other bugs as well, but there's no point in looking for more bugs, when this is pretty much already a show-stopper.

Comment: I would like to know how this answer is related to OP question, and why he gets a segfault in that `++testcount;`

Comment: Once you have undefined behavior, all bets are off. Once undefined behavior occurs, a subsequent crash can occur anywhere, or nowhere.

Comment: Thank you.  I changed the constructor to

Comment: (took too long to edit)

Thank you.  I changed the constructor to
    Compar_Concrete(Func &f) : m_f(f) {}`
and that made it work. 

I'm surprised that it could pass by value without a compiler error, as the copy constructors are explicitly deleted.  That's another question, though.

BTW, I'm using the void*s because I'm showing how to use a lambda for the comparator function in the stdlib function qsort.  qsort uses (const) void*.

Comment: P.S. I didn't mean any snark with the italics.  I put an asterisk between the 'void' and 's' at the beginning and end and the italics, intending to identify a void pointer, the but mini-markdown (of which I wasn't previously aware) italicized the characters between the asterisks.